# Why does putty store sessions in the registry?

Tags: design, data, session

I recently wanted to copy my putty config from one laptop to another.

I figured there would be a directory somewhere which stored the IP addresses etc as some form of text file. I was surprised to learn that that information is stored in the registry and so I had to export a registry key.

I'm curious as to why the details are stored in the registry and not in a text-type file somewhere in the filesystem?

Comment: This question can only be answered by Simon Tatham. You'll have to ask him.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Short answer - Developer's choice.

A couple of decades ago, it was fashionable to drop everything into the Windows Registry, because it was easy to do and it meant you didn't have to worry about where the files wound up in the file system.  With the advent of User Account Control and file system "Virtualisation" (where files were silently redirected somewhere *other* than where you wanted them to be), this was even more attractive.

Nowadays, it's fashionable (and, Sanity-preserving) to leave the Windows Registry for Windows itself to play with.  It's easier to work in the file system, where files can be easily read and written (with UAC rules, of course), replicated elsewhere, backed up *separately* from the inner workings of the Operating System itself and many other, Good Reasons.